# Load data from https without valid certificate in Flash Editor

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm trying to load some data from a https-server that when you visit via a browser returns "The security certificate presented by this website has expired or is not yet valid.". But when i accept anyway, the flash on the page page load data.

But when loading from the Flash Editor it return a:
[IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032: Stream Error. URL: https://{url}"]

Can anyone confirm that this is what is returned when loading data in Flash Editor from a https server without a valid certificate? Or could there be another problem? The url to the https-server is "changed" via the hosts-file in Windows. Could this cause any error? I have tried changing the hosts pointing to my local webserver, wich works fine, but that isn't via https.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Flash CS5.5, URLRequest with URLLoader: 
I tried to load gif image from domain with valid SSL and it loaded OK.
Then I tried to load image from domain with invalid SSL and it didn't load.